# Selecting x number of elements from a System.Collections.Generic.List c#

Tags: c#, list

What i need is a way to select the **last 100 elements** from a list, as list

```
    public List<Model.PIP> GetPIPList()
    {
        if (Repository.PIPRepository.PIPList == null)
            Repository.PIPRepository.Load();
        return Repository.PIPRepository.PIPList.Take(100);

    }
```

I get error like this

'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your list is large, you'll get the best performance by rolling your own:

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> LastItems<T>(this IList<T> list, int numberOfItems) //Can also handle arrays
    {
        for (int index = Math.Max(list.Count - numberOfItems, 0); index < list.Count; index++)
            yield return list[index];
    }
}
```

Why is this faster than using Skip()?  If you have a list with 50,000 items, Skip() calls MoveNext() on the enumerator 49,900 times before it starts returning items.

Why is it faster than using Reverse()?  Because Reverse allocates a new array large enough to hold the list's elements, and copies them into the array.  This is especially good to avoid if the array is large enough to go on the large object heap.

Comment: Thanks man ur right! I would have to deal with 7000+ data at minimum.

Answer (score 11):

```
somelist.Reverse().Take(100).Reverse().ToList();
```

This would be much cheaper than ordering :) Also preserves the original ordering.

Comment: but those two reversals are expensive

Comment: @phoog: reversal is very cheap.

Comment: Is O(n) cheap? I have an app with lists holding tens of thousands of elements, and I am pretty sure that skip/take would do a lot better than 2 reversals.

Comment: @phoog: The second reversal is limited to maximum 100 elements. Using the skip/take approach requires calling count as well.

Comment: also the first Reverse mutates the list, while the second allocates a 100-element array to reverse the items.

Comment: @phoog: No it does not. See Enumerable.Reverse() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497.aspx

Comment: If the static type of `somelist` is `List<T>` then your code sample is calling `List<T>.Reverse()` which mutates the list.

Comment: Actually your code sample doesn't compile, because `List<T>.Reverse()` returns void.  So if you cast the list to `IEnumerable<T>`, you're allocating two arrays, one list-sized, and one list-sized or 100 elements, whichever is smaller.

Comment: @phoog: Wht are you assuming somelist is `List<T>` and not `IEnumerable<T>` or `IQueryable<T>`?  If it bothers you, just do `somelist.ToEnumerable()`.

Comment: @phoog: Also, if somelist is in fact a `List<T>`, `Enumerable.Reverse`  would in essence be a NO-OP given it just returns elements from the bottom of the list. So not even `O(n)` in the worse case.

Comment: Actually I'm looking at the decompiled code and I don't see where Enumerable.Reverse is list-aware.  It creates an instance of the internal Buffer<> struct and copies the items over.

Comment: @phoog: Perhaps a missed optimization opportunity? What did Jon Skeet do in EduLinq?

Comment: No doubt!  I don't know EduLinq.

Comment: @phoog: Actually it does. Look at the constructor of `Buffer<T>`. `List<T>` implements `ICollection<T>`.

Comment: @phoog: I agree it copies the elements, but again, `memcpy` is cheap.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: I missed that you said you wanted the last 100 items, and weren't able to do that yet.

To get the last 100 items:

```
return Repository.PIPRepository.PIPList
    .OrderByDescending(pip=>pip.??).Take(100)
    .OrderBy(pip=>pip.??);
```

...and then change your method signature to return `IEnumerable<Model.PIP>`

`??` signifies what ever property you would be sorting on.

Joel also gives a great solution, based on counting the number of items in the last, and skipping all but 100 of them. In many cases, that probably works better. I didn't want to post the same solution in my edit! :)

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I actually completely edited my answer because I didn't realize he didn't know how to get the last 100; I hung up on the `List<>`/`IEnumerable<>` thing.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
public List<Model.PIP> GetPIPList()
    {
        if (Repository.PIPRepository.PIPList == null)
            Repository.PIPRepository.Load();
        return Repository.PIPRepository.PIPList.Take(100).ToList();

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `.Take()` method returns and `IEnumerable<T>` rather than a `List<T>`.  This is a *good thing*, and you should strongly consider altering your method and your work habits to use `IEnumerable<T>` rather than `List<T>` as much as is practical.

Aside from that, `.Take(100)` will also return the *first* 100 elements, rather than the last 100 elements. You want something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Model.PIP> GetPIPs()
{
    if (Repository.PIPRepository.PIPList == null)
        Repository.PIPRepository.Load();
    return Repository.PIPRepository.PIPList.Skip(Math.Max(0,Repository.PIPRepository.PIPList.Count - 100));
}
```

If you *really* need a list rather than an enumerable (hint: you probably don't), it's still better to build this method using an IEnumerable and use `.ToList()` at the place where you call this method.

At some point in the future you'll want to go back and update your Load() code to also use IEnumerable, as well as code later on in the process. The ultimate goal here is to get to the point where you are effectively streaming your objects to the browser, and only ever one have one of them loaded into memory on your web server at a time. IEnumerable allows for this. List does not.

Comment: if the `Count` is less than `100` for instance `99` records are there then `Invalid index exception` will be thrown.

Comment: are skip and take optimized to use random access for lists? if not, rolling your own would perform better if your lists are large.